# GroupByKey after Windowing in Apache Beam (2.5.0) does not produce output

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using Fixed Window that I apply to a PCollection in order to do GroupBy on an unbounded source like below :

```
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<CustomObject>>> grouppedBy =
    rootObjects.apply(ParDo.of(keyCollection()))
    .apply(
        Window.<KV<String, CustomObject>>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(200))))
.apply(GroupByKey.<String, CustomObject>create());


   private DoFn<CustomObject, KV<String, CustomObject>> keyCollection() {
    return new DoFn<CustomObject, KV<String, CustomObject>>() {
      /**
       *
       */
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(final ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
        CustomObject obj = c.element();
                 String key = obj.getKey();
        Instant date = new DateTime().toInstant();
        c.outputWithTimestamp(KV.of(key, obj), date);
      }
    };
  }
```

And there is no single output in .apply(GroupByKey.create()) step

As I understood from documentation applying Window should give possibility to use GroupByKey on an unbounded source.

Comment: Can you add the rest of the pipeline code? Does it work without the Window and GroupByKey? Are you testing on Dataflow or using the DirectRunner?

Comment: I have found out that the problem was in the next ParDo that process 'grouppedBy collection, basically infinitive loop was giving problem, would not expect this to affect previous transform and to be honest I dont really understand why it does affects

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue while doing CoGroupByKey in unbounded PCollection with Windowing function. In case of Unbounded PCollection you need to use Trigger with Window function to produce the output. Try using Trigger on your window function and then do GroupByKey or CoGroupByKey and it will start producing results.